# How to create following tetrahedral structures

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to using python3 automatically slice cubic box into several tetrahedrons. Like the following figures

[image: Tetrahedron in one unit cell]

and

[image: Tetrahedrons in 27 unit cells]

We know in one unit cell, we can find four vertices and generate a tetrahedron, as in Figure 1. While we increase the number of unit cells, there are limitations need to meet, each vertice can only have a maximum of 4 edges and all tetrahedron should connect with each other by vertices. Like in figure 2. Now I want to automatically find the vertices meet the limitations with more number of unit cells like 100+.

Could anyone provide any ideas? Really appreciate!!

The coordinates of vertices in figure 2 are shown as following:

```
cell1 = [[-1, 1, 1, -1],    #cell structure as cell1 = [[xcoord], [ycoord], [zcoord]]
     [-1, -1, 1, 1],
     [1, -1, 1, -1]]
cell2 = [[1, 3, 1, 3], 
      [3, 3, 1, 1],
      [3, 1, 1, 3]]
cell3 = [[1, -1, 1, -1],
      [3, 5, 5, 3],
      [3, 3, 5, 5]]
cell4 = [[3, 5, 5, 3],
      [3, 5, 3, 5],
      [1, 1, -1, -1]]
cell5 = [[3, 5, 3, 5],
      [1, -1, -1, 1],
      [3, 3, 5, 5]]
```

Drawing codes as:

```py
def plotBox(A2, A3, A4, A5, A6):
    plt.figure()
    ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')

    verts2 = [list(zip(A2[0], A2[1], A2[2]))]
    verts3 = [list(zip(A3[0], A3[1], A3[2]))]
    verts4 = [list(zip(A4[0], A4[1], A4[2]))]
    verts5 = [list(zip(A5[0], A5[1], A5[2]))]
    verts6 = [list(zip(A6[0], A6[1], A6[2]))]

    ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection(verts2, facecolors='w', linewidths=2, alpha=0.5), zs=z)
    ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection(verts3, facecolors='r', linewidths=2, alpha=1), zs=x)
    ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection(verts4, facecolors='w', linewidths=2, alpha=1), zs=x)
    ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection(verts5, facecolors='w', linewidths=2, alpha=1), zs=x)
    ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection(verts6, facecolors='w', linewidths=2, alpha=1), zs=x)
    plt.show()

A2 = [[-1, 1, 1, -1],
     [-1, -1, 1, 1],
     [1, -1, 1, -1]]
A3 = [[1, 3, 1, 3], 
      [3, 3, 1, 1],
      [3, 1, 1, 3]]
A4 = [[1, -1, 1, -1],
      [3, 5, 5, 3],
      [3, 3, 5, 5]]
A5 = [[3, 5, 5, 3],
      [3, 5, 3, 5],
      [1, 1, -1, -1]]
A6 = [[3, 5, 3, 5],
      [1, -1, -1, 1],
      [3, 3, 5, 5]]
plotBox(A2, A3, A4, A5, A6)
```